# Does PHP have syntax sugar for `defined('X') && X`?

Tags: php, constants, syntactic-sugar

I often have to check the value of a constant, but it's not guaranteed that to exist. The typical way is `if ( defined( 'X' ) && X )`, but that gets annoying to type when a constant has a good, descriptive name.

It feels like there should be a shortcut, something like `constant( 'X', $default_value )` or `if ( X ?? false )`, but haven't found anything that works. Everything throws an `E_WARNING`, returns an unexpected value, or both.

I could write my own `constant_value( $name, $default )` function, but that would have to be added to every project I work on, and would be a non-standard thing for other devs to have to learn.

I don't see any [RFC's](https://wiki.php.net/rfc) that seem relevant.

I'm guessing the answer is "no", but wanted to make sure I haven't missed something.

Comment: I'm afraid that you need to stick with `defined()`. However, regarding creating your own function for it, I don't see why that would be an issue. Sure, other devs needs to learn that, but they still need to learn the rest of the code base so I don't see why a helper function that makes your life easier would be a big issue. I would rather ask why you don't know that those constants are defined? Maybe you could challenge how use use them in the first place, or possibly defined them with default values somewhere when you boot the app if they aren't defined?

Comment: Adding it to dozens of current projects and hundreds of future ones seems almost as inconvenient as just using `defined()`. I get your point about learning the whole codebase, but the cost/benefit just doesn't seem worth it to me.

Comment: Making sure constants are always defined is a good thought, but even then I'd want to explicitly check them. I introduced a security bug once because I assumed something was defined, and don't want to rely on future devs following an unenforced convention. Maybe when PHP makes undefined constants an `E_ERROR`, though. I'm often working with 3rd party code too, though.

Comment: Second @M.Eriksson's note, good idea to have a boot-up routine that ensures all constants used in the code are defined. If you have constants that may or may not be defined at any given run, it also begs the question whether you should be using constants there to begin with. On your note _"annoying to type when a constant has a good, descriptive name"_, there is obviously no syntax candy there, you could could define aliases for longer constants. Really it seems that `defined()` is the lesser annoyance compared to typing `JSON_UNESCAPED_LINE_TERMINATORS` etc. -- which an IDE might help with?

Comment: In modern versions of PHP, `echo FOOBAR;` results in fatal error, and as such it doesn't seem like security bugs would potentially follow from undefined constants. I'd just let the code die and see where that happens, and then ensure that such constants _are_ consistently defined. There's no real performance gain to be had from having a hundred constants more or less defined at bootup. If you have rarely called modules that require particular constants specific to them, consider using class constants, or otherwise task the modules with defining their own constants when instantiated.

Comment: _"but even then I'd want to explicitly check them"_ - Sure, but you do it in one single place. _"don't want to rely on future devs following an unenforced convention"_ - You're making this into a way bigger deal than it is. Tbh, having one file that checks it and sets default is actually very nice (I've worked with similar setups and it was pretty clear how it would be used and you had a good overview). If you document it and still don't trust devs to follow the guidelines of the code, why would you even let them touch it in the first place?

Comment: You make it sound like you have dozens of constants scattered all over the place. How are you actually using the constants? As configuration? Then there are cleaner ways than using constants. Relying too much on constants can also make your code much harder to test.

Comment: If there is indeed a need for global configuration constants, constants can also be arrays... `const SYS_CFG = ['foo' => 1, 'bar' => 2, 'throw_rocks' => true, 'if_what_happen' => 'exit'];` etc. You can use null-coalescence then, `if(SYS_CFG['plant_flowers'] ?? true)` -- but anything that goes into your config constant array _will have to be defined in one statement_. I tend to do that e.g. for global paths, where e.g. `const BASEDIRS = ['files' => 'files/', 'logs' => '../logs/', 'static' => 'www/static'];` etc. Still, it is of course tidier if your classes don't use these internally.

Comment: PHP 8+ is only running on ~34% of servers, so relying on that fatal isn't safe in my context. I'm not concerned about micro-optimizations. I don't think it's reasonable/wise to rely on devs reading docs and bootstrap code every time they come back to a project a year later; straightforward is simple, and simple is best. I feel like y'all are making it harder than it needs to be; I'm not gonna propose a refactor of 15 year old codebases, and shoehorn modern design patterns onto 3rd party frameworks, just so I can assume globals exist. It's totally ok that the answer is "no".